# What does "ShellExecuteEx failed; code 18" mean (on vista)

Tags: windows-vista, shellexecuteex

A buddy of mine has been getting this error mesage when trying to run uninstall programs andor new program apps, windows just shows "ShellExecuteEx failed; code 18" and refuses to run the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) explains the system call he tries to make.

A little googling the error codes suggests that `18` means `SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED` (In the list the previous one is `11` and the next is `27`)

In case this is **NOT** a programming question, please head over to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)